# Volume of the solid bounded below

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Use a triple integral to find the volume
of the solid bounded below by 
$$z = x^2+y^2$$

and bounded above by

$$z = 8 − 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

How would you set up this integral?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. :) A very similar question is asked [in this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554150/volume-of-solid-w-delimited-by-z-x23y2-and-z-8-x2-y2/1560161#1560161). You can take a look at it. I am sure that it will suffice. :)

Comment: Thanks it seems to be using a change of variable

Comment: One of the answers uses a change of variables and the other one (Mine) don't! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $z$ integral is just the difference between the two functions, and the remaining 2-dimensional integral can be done in polar coordinates.

Explicitly,

$$\eqalign{
&\int_{f_1(x,y)<f_2(x,y)}\int_{z=f_1(x,y)}^{f_2(x,y)}dz dx dy\\
&=\int_{f_1(x,y)<f_2(x,y)}(f_2(x,y)-f_1(x,y)) dx dy\\
&=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^2(8-2r-r^2)rdrd\theta\\
}$$

Comment: This is the cylindrical method?

Comment: @GuestCalc: never heard of such a method but there is definitely cylinder symmetry in the problem and in my proposal.

Comment: Sorry I meant cylindrical coordinates

Comment: @GuestCalc OK that's what it is. Is this sufficient hint or would you like a more explicit expression for the integral?

Comment: If you could provide one it would be really helpful

Comment: Doesn't r go from 0 to 4 because of f2

Comment: It cuts underneath $f_1$ beyond $r=2.$