# Calculating the volume between 2 arbitrary paraboloids

Tags: volume, multiple-integral

I have surfaces with equations
$$z=ax^2+by^2 \quad\text{and}\quad
z=6-cx^2-dy^2.$$

I want to find the volume bounded between the these two surfaces (obviously paraboloids). I tried to use multiple integrals, but turns out to be impossible. I'm thinking how do I use some linear transformation of the coordinates to make it an easier integral? Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585444/find-the-volume-between-two-paraboloids) for some inspiration.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps consider using  cylindrical coordinates to integrate.

Comment: For the beginning: do you have some clue what is the shape of the intersection curve of these paraboloids? How to even start to compute the volume when you don't know it?

Comment: Maybe you should explore the problem first by giving values to $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've managed to solve the problem at the end after changing variables and integrating over the region of the intersection curve (which is an ellipse).

Comment: Note that the projection of the intersection curve down to the x,y plane is indeed an ellipse. However, for general choice of constants $a,b,c,d > 0,$ namely when $ad-bc \neq 0,$ the actual curve in x,y,z space does not lie in a plane. Somewhat too extreme, think of the laces on a baseball.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
V & \equiv
\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}\bracks{z > ax^{2} + by^{2}}
\bracks{z < 6 - cx^{2} - dy^{2}}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{ax^{2} + by^{2} < z <  6 - cx^{2} - dy^{2}}\dd z\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}
\bracks{ax^{2} + by^{2} < 6 - cx^{2} - dy^{2}}
\int_{ax^{2} + by^{2}}^{6 - cx^{2} - dy^{2}}\dd z\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
6\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}
\bracks{{a + c \over 6}\,x^{2} + {b + d \over 6}\,y^{2} < 1}
\pars{1 - {a + c \over 6}\,x^{2} - {b + d \over 6}\,y^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\end{align}

> With $\ds{\pars{~\root{a + c \over 6}x \mapsto x~}}$ and
>   $\ds{\pars{~\root{b + d \over 6}y \mapsto y~}}$:

\begin{align}
V & =
{36 \over \root{\pars{a + c}\pars{b + d}}}
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} < 1}
\pars{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\substack{2D\ Cyl. \\ Coord.}}{=}\,\,\,
{36 \over \root{\pars{a + c}\pars{b + d}}}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}
\pars{1 - r^{2}}r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi =
\bbx{{18\pi \over \root{\pars{a + c}\pars{b + d}}}}
\end{align}